# Add column in regression output

Tags: r, regression, chi-squared, exp

I would like to add a column with the X² (Chi-Square) as well as a column with the Exp(B) into my regression output. Is there any idea on how to do this? Many thanks in advance. For now i have calculated this manually for every model and variable, which is quite time consuming.

```
model_simple <- as.formula("completion_yesno ~  ac + ov + UCRate + FirstWeek + LastWeek + DayofWeekSu + DayofWeekMo + DayofWeekTu + DayofWeekWe + DayofWeekTh + DayofWeekFr + MonthofYearJan + MonthofYearFeb + MonthofYearMar + MonthofYearApr +MonthofYearMay+ MonthofYearJun + MonthofYearJul + MonthofYearAug + MonthofYearSep + MonthofYearOct + MonthofYearNov")
clog_simple1 = glm(model_simple,data=cllw,family = binomial(link = cloglog))
summary(clog_simple1)
```

Comment: Please show how you *calculated this manually for every model and variable*. Also, not clear what you mean about *column* in regression output as `summary` of a model returns a list of many different (vector/matix/list) elements.

Comment: you can make a data.frame out of summary(clog_simple1), but what do you mean by add chi-square? This has to come from some calculation on your side i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can elaborate on what you mean by chi-square and exp(B). You can do the below:

```
da <- MASS::Pima.tr
model <- glm(type ~ .,data=da,family = binomial(link = cloglog))
results <- data.frame(coefficients(summary(model)),check.names=FALSE)
# some random values
results$chisq = rchisq(nrow(results),1)
results$expB = exp(results$Estimate)
```

Or you can use tidy from broom:

```
library(broom)
results = tidy(model)
results$expB = exp(results$Estimate)
```